# jquery.validate.unobtrusive conflict with Chosen and Cleditor JS

Tags: javascript

I have added:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript">
```

but whenever I am using `CLEDITOR JS` validation stop working. I think there is a conflict between validation and cleditor.

```
$('.cleditor').cleditor();
```

The same is with `CHOSEN JS` plugin:

```
$('[data-rel="chosen"],[rel="chosen"]').chosen();
```

what can I do? I am searching but I can not find a solution. If I remove this two lines then works.